# ie7 jquery not binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to bind some click events with jQuery. Everything works in Chrome, FF, and (surprisingly IE 6). However, it doesn't work in IE 7/8. I'm trying to bind 'click' to a label. I've tried all of the following and nothing seems to work:

```
$('label').bind('click', function(){
  alert('label clicked');
});
```

or

```
$('label').click(function(){
  alert('label clicked');
);
```

or

```
// added a class to all labels
$('.label').bind('click', function(){
  alert('label clicked');
});
```

or

```
// added a class to all labels
$('.label').click(function(){
  alert('label clicked');
});
```

In all the browsers I listed, I'll get a nice alert box, EXCEPT IE 7/8. Is this a jQuery issue, am I missing something, or what? I'm really confused because I've never had a problem like this before...

Comment: I see no issue in this code, may be some other script error before this is causing the issue?? Did you see any script issues...

Comment: Something not working in IE?  I don't believe it :)

Comment: @Teja - its the ONLY js on the page :). I consider myself a skilled debugger, so I made a completely blank page and I'm STILL getting this error...

Comment: @drpcken - The weird thing is that it works in IE 6

Comment: probably not going to help, but did you try using live() instead of bind()? Also, are you using the latest version of Jquery?

Comment: Good Call Zevan, I was able to get it to work in IE8 and Chrome by using live() instead of bind().  Make an answer and see if it works for him :)

Comment: Hmm... are you adding this piece of js on page load??

Comment: Are you sure the page is not cached in IE7 with an older version of the JS/HTML?

Comment: @Zevan - add an answer so I can mark it as correct please :)

Comment: :) glad it worked, added as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using live() instead of bind(). Also, are you using the latest version of jquery?

Comment: most recent yes, live fixed it